# Convert in CFDataRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets

I have a problem.
i want convert my object "Position" in a CFDataRef for sending it in the TCP Socket.
I don't know how i can do.
Can you help me?

```
@interface Position : NSObject {

    NSString *name;

    float valueX;
    float valueY;
    float valueZ;

}

-(BOOL)setValue:(NSString*)name:(float)valueX:(float)valueY:(float)valueZ;

@property (nonatomic,readwrite, retain)   NSString      *name;

@property (readwrite)   float      valueX;
@property (readwrite)   float      valueY;
@property (readwrite)   float      valueZ;


@end




//In another class after the correct connection.
    Position *tempPosition = [[Position alloc]init];

    for(int i=0; i<[arrayPosition count]; i++){
        tempPosition = [arrayPosition objectAtIndex:i];
        //I want have a CFDataRef of tempPosition for sending. dataSend is my CFDataRef variable
        CFSocketSendData(socketAccept, NULL, dataSend, 0);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use [`NSKeyedArchiver`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Looks like this and returns an `NSData` object (which is the same as -- has a toll-free bridge with -- `CFDataRef`):

```
NSData *tileData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theTile];
```

(This from the [CopyPasteTile](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CopyPasteTile/Listings/Classes_ColorTileView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009040-Classes_ColorTileView_m-DontLinkElementID_4) sample code.)

However, if you're copying data between machines... I wonder if this is the right approach? According to the [Binary Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Concepts/DataObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000171-CJBDBHCB):

> In particular, it will not handle
>   byte-order swapping when distributed
>   between big-endian and little-endian
>   machines. (In Cocoa, use NSValue for
>   typed data.)

I'm not saying it won't work, but it's certainly something to think about.